# How to update dynamic query param api url in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, query-string

I'm trying to update the api url in my reactjs app using the onchange event on the inputs of a form. The purpose is to perform debounce data search. Is there a way to update the url dynamically according to the input ? I am using react router dom v6.All the cases I found are just update param on browser url. Not like string. Thanks for all the help!

### Base URL:

```
api/v1/notions
```

### Expect url:

- Input name has value 'xxx'

```
api/v1/notions?name=xxx
```

- Input age has value '18'

```
api/v1/notions?name=xxx&age=18
```

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service. Do you have a [mcve] for what you are trying to do? Is there an issue with it? Can you clarify what you are asking for?

Comment: @DrewReese I solved the problem using the solution below. Thank you for responding !

Comment: I see. What version of `react-router-dom` are you using? If using v6 why not just use the `useSearchParams` hook and set the query params you need, or just manually create a [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object and set them?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Hope it will be useful to someone!

```
const generateURLQueryParam = (url, objParams) => {
  const objFormatted = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(objParams).filter(([_, v]) => v != null && v !== "")
  );
  if (Object.keys(objFormatted).length === 0) {
    return url;
  }

  const str =
    url +
    "?" +
    Object.keys(objFormatted)
      .map((key) => {
        return objFormatted[key] === "" || objFormatted[key] === null
          ? ""
          : `${key}=${encodeURIComponent(objFormatted[key])}`;
      })
      .join("&");

  return str;
};
```

## generate uri:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const filter1 = {
      page: "",
      limit: "d",
    };

    const filter2 = {
      page: "",
      limit: "",
    };

    const filter3 = {
      page: "d",
      limit: "f",
    };

    console.log(generateURLQueryParam("search", filter1)); //search?limit=d
    console.log(generateURLQueryParam("search", filter2)); //search
    console.log(generateURLQueryParam("search", filter3)); //search?page=d&limit=f
  }, []);
```